# adding reference to dll does not bring the namespace

Tags: .net, dll, namespaces, reference

I have a solution containing several projects. I renamed one of the projects, and add a reference to it from one of the other projects.

After all, when trying to include the newly renamed project in the other project with "Using" keyword, it does not recognize the renamed namespace, so I cannot use any of the classes that I have got on it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you add the new reference to other projects too?

Comment: after renaming the project just build the whole solution and then try to add the reference.

Comment: @mahesh: I actually have cleaned and rebuild the whole solution but no luck :(

Comment: @user609130: just to check can you just copy the dll of newly created project to the bin folder of other project and try to add reference to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restarted visual studio and it now works fine!

Do not know what was the reason, but if you've encountered same thing and tried all the comments above, with no success, just close and reopen VS, should be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed the assembly this probably doesn't rename the namespaces inside. So make sure that the class you are trying to use belongs to the proper namespace.

Comment: I have safely renamed the namespace of all files within that project to conform to the name of the project, still does not work

Comment: @user609130, try manually deleting the old assembly from the output folder.

Comment: Have deleted the reference to the renamed project, and added that again, no success. is that what you mean?